# install app file in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have an app file which i need to install in sharepoint farm. I'm using SP2013 on premise version, So is this feasible to install app instead of wsp and if yes, please guide me ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done by following the below steps :

Assume that app configuration for the SharePoint farm is already done.

**Create a App Catalog for the Web Application.**
**Upload this App file to this App catalog.**
**Added app file can be installed in all the site collections under the web application.**
[image]

in the app catalog site under Apps for SharePoint upload the app file :

[image]

these apps will be available to add in the site from **Add an App** option in the sites.

if the environment is not configured for SharePoint Apps , Kindly follow the below article to do the same .

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx